# Why is jenkins slow on one machine and perfect on other

Tags: performance, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on two machines.Images are attached for both the machines configurations. The machine with CPU E5-2687W v4 @3.00 GHz, performs faster than the other. The average response time for a query in this machine is 430 ms. However, on the other machine it 1.3 sec.

Does Jenkins performance has to do anything with processor speed ? In both the machines, Jenkins is allocated 16GB of RAM space.

**Machine 1. Slow working Jenkins:**

[image: Machine 1. Slow working Jenkins]

**Machine 2. Fast working Jenkins:**

[image: Machine 2. Fast working Jenkins]

Comment: Processor speed will help in terms of the amount of time it takes to complete builds. One thing I noticed, though, is limiting the number of builds retained on the server improves the Jenkins app performance greatly. The more builds, the longer it takes to access Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. Jenkins performance does have to do something with processor speed (and it depends on a plethora of other factors as well).